# Getting Original Size from Tiled PostGIS Raster

Tags: raster, postgis-2.0

Does anybody know of a quick and easy get the original height and width (rows and columns) of a tiled raster in PostGIS?

Using a combination of items I know this can be calculated so just wondering if there is a canned function I am missing somewhere.  I am running PostGIS 2.1.4.

Answer (score 2):

This is at least one version of the SQL too:

```
SELECT MIN(ST_UpperLeftX(rast)) AS min_x, 
  MAX(ST_UpperLeftX(rast) + (ST_Width(rast) * ST_PixelWidth(rast))) AS max_x,
  MIN(ST_UpperLeftY(rast) - (ST_Height(rast) * ST_PixelHeight(rast))) AS min_y,
  MAX(ST_UpperLeftY(rast)) AS max_y,
  (MAX(ST_UpperLeftX(rast) + (ST_Width(rast) * ST_PixelWidth(rast))) - 
    MIN(ST_UpperLeftX(rast))) / MAX(ST_PixelWidth(rast)) AS num_cols,
  (MAX(ST_UpperLeftY(rast)) - 
    MIN(ST_UpperLeftY(rast) - (ST_Height(rast) * ST_PixelHeight(rast)))) / 
    MAX(ST_PixelHeight(rast)) AS num_rows
  FROM my_raster_table;

   min_x   |   max_x   |  min_y  |  max_y  | num_cols | num_rows 
-----------+-----------+---------+---------+----------+----------
 -12802000 | -11465000 | 3503000 | 4440000 |     5348 |     3748
```

Comment: This looks like it should be part of the question as its code attempt.